# How to use a value retrieved from a table in a pipeline adf?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have done a lookup to retrieve the data from a table, I have looped through the data from that table with a for each and I need to modify another field of the table in each looped field I have tried with UPDATE dbo.Packages SET startDate= GETDATE() WHERE column=@value in a script and in a lookup but it does not receive the value retrieved in the for each.

Comment: Could you please provide some input and output?

Comment: as it is within the for each iteration, you would have to use item()

Comment: I have used item() in the script as sql but it is not returning anything.

Comment: Could you please provide the error what you have got along with pipeline image?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your issue with below sql table

[image]

by retrieving value from look up activty with below query

```
UPDATE [dbo].[<tableName>] SET startDate= GETDATE() WHERE Name='@{activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].<columnName>}'
```

[image]

I tried with below query in script activity in foreach activity

```
UPDATE dbo.Employees SET startDate= GETDATE() WHERE Name='@{item().<columnName>}'
```

It executed successfully.

[image]

and values updated successfully.

[image]